# 'Meaning' of a triple integral with $f(x,y,z)\neq 1$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm studying for my Calculus II exam, and this question came to my mind while I was practising integals with spherical coordinates.

Probably this question doesn't have sense at all, but there's a geometric interpretation of an hypervolume so I can imagine what the result of a triple integral over a function $f(x,y,z)\neq 1$ does it mean?

Thank you!

Comment: If the function measures density at each point, then the integral signifies weight.

Comment: Refer Lecture 8,9 of this video series for explanation of concept and question you are asking .These are by professor Adrian banner of princeton university https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGqzsq0erqU7h6_bpE-CgJp4iX5aRju28