# multivariate calculus - what is triple integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Calculating of double integral on a some intervals gives us the volume of an 3d object, what about a triple integral, it gives the volume of 4d object?

Comment: A double integral is typically used to calculate areas (not volumes). A triple integral is commonly used to calculate volumes. Nothing stops you from calculating the $n$-volume of some $n$-dimensional object using an $n$-fold integral.

Then again, $n$-fold integrals can have a completely different interpretation altogether. Any physical interpretation is always dependend on the context. The variables need not always represent a spacial dimension.

Comment: See some applications, as well as properties, of triple integrals: https://www.math24.net/properties-applications-triple-integrals/

Comment: See also ['Meaning' of a triple integral with $f(x,y,z)\ne1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1116209/26369)